# ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CURRENCY' from 'moneyed' on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django

I've been using Django for just over a year for the development of an automation software and am currently just running the project locally on my windows machine.
I hadn't run into any issues with it, until I tried running cron tasks, which ofc windows doesn't support. Scheduled tasks don't work the same way imo, so I installed a Ubuntu VM to work with the project.
Set everything up correctly(I think?), installed Django and all. Currently installing all the libraries the project uses, one of which is django-money. I have installed it, as well as py-moneyed, yet on trying to make migrations, or run the server, I run into this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN2gr.png)
Can't find anything about this online. The project still works perfectly with the windows command prompt, as well as PowerShell but having this issue on the ubuntu VM.

Installed apps on my settings.py look like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'bootstrap5',
'sass_processor',
'djmoney',
'background_task',
'django_crontab',
'companies',
'google_cal',
'dashboard',
```

]

Any help on this, or good alternative for corn tasks-need some to run every 2 hours and update the db and others to run once a day at a specific time. Celery also does not work with Windows.

The full error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                             
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv
/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv                                   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                                                                                                                         
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute                            super().execute(*args, **options)                                                                                                                                                          
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute                                         output = self.handle(*args, **options)                                                                                                                                                     
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle                             if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:                                                                                                                                      
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__                                             self._setup(name)                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup                                                  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)                                                                                                                                                  
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__                                               mod = 
importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)                                                                                                                                        
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                                                                                                                    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                              
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                            
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                            
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module                                                                                                                      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                 
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/automation_software/automation_software/settings.py", line 16, in <module>                                                            
from djmoney.settings import FIXER_ACCESS_KEY                                                                                                                                              
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djmoney/settings.py", line 6, in <module>                                                     
from moneyed import CURRENCIES, DEFAULT_CURRENCY, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE                                                                                                                  
ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CURRENCY' from 'moneyed' (/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moneyed/__init__.py)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                             
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                                                                                         main()                                                                                                                                                                                     
File "manage.py", line 18, in main                                                                                                                                                             execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                        
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line                   utility.execute()                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute                                     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                                                                    
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 367, in run_from_argv                                   connections.close_all()                                                                                                                                                                    
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in close_all                                                   for alias in self:                                                                                                                                                                         
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__                                             return 
iter(self.settings)                                                                                                                                                                 
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__                                              res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)                                                                                                                                   
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in 
settings                                             self._settings = 
self.configure_settings(self._settings)                                                                                                                                   
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings                                          databases = 
super().configure_settings(databases)                                                                                                                                          
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings                                   settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)                                                                                                                                    
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__                                             self._setup(name)                                                                                                                                                                          
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup                                                  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)                                                                                                                                                  
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__                                               mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)                                                                                                                                        
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                                                                                                                    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                              
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                            
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                            
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module                                                                                                                      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in 
_call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                 
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/automation_software/automation_software/settings.py", line 16, in <module>                                                            
from djmoney.settings import FIXER_ACCESS_KEY                                                                                                                                              
File "/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djmoney/settings.py", line 6, in <module>                                                     
from moneyed import CURRENCIES, DEFAULT_CURRENCY, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE                                                                                                                  
ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CURRENCY' from 'moneyed' (/mnt/f/Django/RC/Sales-automation/sales-automation/ubuntu_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moneyed/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That constant has been removed in version 2.0. See this link https://github.com/py-moneyed/py-moneyed/blob/ef5d65da3e6e774a377b6e1434a051f0454d2193/CHANGES.rst

Comment: Both py-moneyed and django-money are up to date, so not sure why it keeps asking for that constant. Shouldn't it remove the requirement itself, considering it's updated?

Comment: In any case djmoney/settings.py is trying to import DEFAULT_CURRENCY in this line: 

from moneyed import CURRENCIES, DEFAULT_CURRENCY, DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE

And moneyed doesn't have DEFAULT_CURRENCY in the latest version. So perhaps you can downgrade moneyed one version until djmoney catches up...